# How do I get the SHA of the latest commit on a GitHub repository via jQuery?

Tags: jquery, json, api, github, commit

I've been at this for several hours now and I have yet to find any useful information anywhere. I'm trying to use jQuery to get the latest commit of any GitHub repository from a single user to show up on my homepage. Currently, this is what I have:

```
$.getJSON("https://api.github.com/users/theinfection/repos", function(data) {
        $(".lastcommit").html('<a href="https://github.com/TheInfection/' + data[0].name + '/commit/' + data[0].sha + '">text</a>');
});
```

That outputs this link: https://github.com/TheInfection/Blue-Monday-HD/commit/undefined. This sort of works but it only shows the latest commit of the first repo listed in the JSON file and it doesn't get the SHA of said commit.

Now, what I want to know is:

- How do I get the SHA of commits?
- How do I sort the commits in chronological order so that the latest is at the top?
- How do I get the commit comment text?

This has been bothering me for a while so any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Would this help?

```
$.getJSON("https://api.github.com/users/theinfection/repos", function(data) {
    $.getJSON(data[0].commits_url.slice(0, -6), function(data) {
        $('.lastcommit').text(data[0].sha);
    });
});
```

In the initial request you get the repos, then take the repo you want and get it's commits. Of course, if you know your repo name already, you can call:

```
var repo = 'TheInfection/Blue-Monday-HD';
$.getJSON("https://api.github.com/repos/" + repo + "/commits", function(data) {
    $('.lastcommit').text(data[0].sha);
});
```

The list is already sorted in the reverse-chronological order and the message and the author are also there: `data[0].commit.message` and `data[0].commit.committer.name`.

Play with it on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jeyey/1/)

Comment: This is closer to what I need but I need a script that'll look at all the repos that a single user has and find the latest commit out of all of them but return only the latest one. For instance, let's say I have 10 repos. Everyday for 10 days I push one commit to each repo. The script I need needs to look at all my repos and return the very last commit I pushed. In this case, it'll be the commit I pushed to the 10th repo on the 10th day.

Comment: With github api v3, this approach no longer works.  Perhaps because the api requires authentication?